# Android Powerdown device after 10 minutes inactive

Tags: android

I need for my app to shutdown the device if there is 10 minutes or more of inactivity.  So what is best way to detect and shutdown after 10 minutes?  Thanks

Comment: Rooted or non-rooted phone/device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only firmware, or possibly apps signed with the firmware signing key, can initiate a shutdown of the device. A regular SDK application cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have kept .flo files with checks and balances at below address 
We need Automate app (play store), Automate root app (play store) , rooted phone or tablet.
In case magisk , Automate to be granted root permissives from Magisk Manager manually if required. But it is after 3 hours.
https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-automate-t2870633/page63

Comment: Please, review your answer to be more specific. You can find info and tips about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer